# Android Front Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.2-froyo

i'm trying to use front camera using this tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

but got a problem that is making me mad.

1st of all, if use the code provided by example, at onClick(View view) the camera is null. is this a mine problem? however, i solved that implementing camera.open() directly in my onClick method.

```
  public void takePhoto(View view) {
      if (!getPackageManager() .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
          cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
          if (cameraId < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
          }
      }
      try{
          PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext());
          camera.takePicture(null, null,photoHandler);
      }catch(Exception c){
          Log.e("error", c.toString(),c.getCause());
      }
  }
```

i added

```
try{
              PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext());
              camera.takePicture(null, null,photoHandler);
          }catch(Exception c){
              Log.e("error", c.toString(),c.getCause());
          }
```

to see what's the problem and logcat tells me

```
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17354)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5231)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    ... 11 more
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Fail to connect to camera service**
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:302)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    at com.example.cameratest.MainActivity.takePhoto(MainActivity.java:34)
05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638):    ... 14 more
```

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cameratest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cameratest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It appears that your camera.open() call is failing: '05-16 17:19:00.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12638): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Fail to connect to camera service**' Could be that it wasn't closed correctly or is in use by another app.  You should surround the camera.open() call with a try/catch block and handle it.

Comment: Bah my app simply do this.. So who can open camera before i do this app.. Bah! However i debugged all the code and when I call  .open(id)  i correctly get an instance of camera... The problem is right in the .takepicture().   I got no exception before that line

Answer (score 2):

OK i solved that problem.
The tutorial was wrong.
Android tutorial tells

```
Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
```

and tutorial was not doing that.
Now everything works fine.

Comment: Where in the code do you call a startPreview();? If I run this in the onCreate(), it indicates I need to make it a separate method. Is there a built in way to call startPreview()?

Answer (score 0):

The camera may need some time to open. You can start the camera in `onResume()` of your activity, this will guarantee that when a user clicks the button, the camera is initialized.

Don't forget to gracefully release the camera when you don't need it anymore, e.g. in `onPause()`.

PS: in the tutorial, the camera is initialized in `onCreate()`. It's not the best choice, especially if the app may be paused and restarted later, because after `onPause()` the camera will be null and `onCreate()` may not be called if the system decides to keep your activity alive.

Comment: Nothing changed..always got that problem :\

Comment: You mean - you call `Camera.open()` in `onResume()`, but still __camera__ is null when you reach the `takePhoto()` method?

Comment: nope,i solved that.Now calling in `onResume()`, when i call camera in `takePhoto(View view)`  is not null. But I got the same problem trying to make a photo, cause now still got `05-20 17:17:11.212: E/class java.lang.RuntimeException(6205): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed`. The diffrence is that now Log simply tells me that, nothing more

Comment: Maybe you should set picture parameters, e.g. size? Do you see the preview before takeFoto() is called?

Comment: uhmmmm preview ? where should i see the preview? because the layout simply got `<Button
        android:id="@+id/captureFront"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Make Photo" />`  so my app is simply a blank page with a button to take photo